# How to create a sparse diagonal matrix?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, diagonal

Might be a very silly question, but I cannot seem to find a proper way to create a sparse diagonal matrix in R. 
I've found the functions:

- `diag.spam()`
- `spdiags()`

and used them with library `Matrix` and package `spam` downloaded, but R did not seem to recognize these functions. Does anyone know a function or library I need to download?

I need it because I want to create diagonal matrices larger than 256 by 256.

Comment: Check library slam.

Answer (score 6):

The `Diagonal()` function in the `Matrix` package. (`Matrix` is a "recommended" package, which means it is automatically available when you install R.)

```
library(Matrix)
m <- Diagonal(500)
image(m)
```

`Diagonal(n)` creates an n x n identity matrix. If you want to create a diagonal matrix with a specified diagonal `x`, use `Diagonal(x=<your vector>)`

Answer (score 1):

Use bandSparse of the Matrix library.

to get an n-by-n matrix with m on its diagonal use, write:

```
bandSparse(n,n,0,list(rep(m, n+1)))
```